# Categorical terminology

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

For any monoidal category $(\mathscr{C},\otimes,I)$ with objects $A,B,...$:

Does the monoidal product $\otimes$ always have the property: $A \otimes A \rightarrow A, B \otimes B \rightarrow B,...$ ? If not then, what is the term used the characterise this property?

Let $F$ be the right functor $X \rightarrow X \otimes A$ induced by object $A$.

For any object $B$, suppose $F$ maps morphism $A \rightarrow B$ to $id_{FA}$. What is this property called? Again, for any object $B$, suppose $F$ instead maps morphism $A \rightarrow B$ to $A \rightarrow B$. What is this property called?

Thanks!

Comment: This will certainly be true whenever $A\in \mathscr{C}$ is a monoid, in which case there is a multiplication $\mu :A\otimes A\to A$ that commutes with the associator. 

As far as the functor $F$ goes, $F(f:A\to B)$ is an arrow :$X \otimes A\to X \otimes B$ so $F(f)=id_{FA}$ makes no sense unless I am missing something. Do you mean $F(f:A\to A)=id_{FA}$ ?

Comment: 1. In the first part of your answer, it that equivalent to enriching the category over a monoid? 2. To clarify that scenario, F maps both objects $A$ and $B$ to $FA$ and maps the morphism $A \rightarrow B$ to the identity morphism $id_{FA}$.

Comment: Sorry, I may have been mistaken about part 1, enrichment appears to only be over the morphisms (hom-set) not the objects themselves.

Comment: What do you mean by the *property* $A\otimes A\to A$ ? That expression is a morphism, not a property.